# How to solve this Type Erasure?

Tags: java

I'm wondering how can I solve this Compilation Failure I got in JDK 1.7, the code works perfectly with JDK 1.6.

**Error I got:** MatchStrings.java:[71,36] error: name clash: with(ElementMatcher) in MatchStrings and with(ElementMatcher) in MatchElements have the same erasure, yet neither hides the other

**My classes in questions:**

```
public class MatchStrings extends MatchElements
{


public static class StringMatcherImpl extends ElementMatcherImpl<String> 
{
    public StringMatcherImpl(ElementMatcher<String> matcher)
    {
        super(matcher);
    }
}

public static class PrefixMatcher implements ElementMatcher<String>
{

    private final String _prefix;

    public PrefixMatcher(String prefix)
    {
        _prefix = prefix;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(String str)
    {
        return str.startsWith(_prefix);
    }
}

public static class SuffixMatcher implements ElementMatcher<String>
{

    private final String _suffix;

    public SuffixMatcher(String suffix)
    {
        _suffix = suffix;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(String str)
    {
        return str.endsWith(_suffix);
    }
}

public static StringMatcherImpl with(ElementMatcher<String> matcher) 
{
    return new StringMatcherImpl(matcher);
}

public static StringMatcherImpl startingWith(String prefix) 
{
    return with(new PrefixMatcher(prefix));
}

public static StringMatcherImpl endingWith(String prefix) 
{
    return with(new SuffixMatcher(prefix));
}
```

}

```
public class MatchElements
{

public static class ElementMatcherImpl<E> implements ElementMatcher<E> 
{
    private ElementMatcher<E> _matcher;

    ElementMatcherImpl(ElementMatcher<E> matcher) 
    {
        _matcher = matcher;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(E e)
    {
        return _matcher.matches(e);
    }

    public ElementMatcherImpl<E> and(ElementMatcher<E> m)
    {
        _matcher = new ElementMatcherAndChain<E>(_matcher, m);
        return this;
    }

    public ElementMatcherImpl<E> or(ElementMatcher<E> m)
    {
        _matcher = new ElementMatcherOrChain<E>(_matcher, m);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return _matcher.toString();
    }
}

public static <E> ElementMatcherImpl<E> with(ElementMatcher<E> matcher) 
{
    return new ElementMatcherImpl<E>(matcher);
}

public static <E> ElementMatcherImpl<E> not(ElementMatcher<E> matcher)
{
    return with(new ElementMatcherNegator<E>(matcher));
}

}
```

Comment: Make the methods non-static, use reified generics or refactor the entire thing to not rely on this. Question is - how did you end up with this code in the first place?

Comment: About "Compiles under Java 6 but not Java 7": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442177/why-didnt-java-type-erasure-prevents-this-code-from-compiling/28442599#28442599.

Comment: @Ordous Some code you will always inherit in real life, if I think about all the projects I have worked in my life only a very small part have been about brand new development, the biggest part have been about maintenance and development of new functionality and the customers often hasn't time or money to refactoring certain silly things.

Comment: @napulitano My comment wasn't meant to degrade the OP or imply it's their fault. It's to point out that if production code (even if it's for tests only) is using a known bug in the compiler, then there might be an entire segment of the code based on shady practices and shortcuts. Finding out how it made its way into the codebase is likely to uncover more (unrelated) problems.

Comment: @Tom in this case the signature of MatchStrings should be a subsignature of MatchElements according to your link: 
Type Erasure
* The signature of m1 is not a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m2.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static StringMatcherImpl with(ElementMatcher<String> matcher)
```

in `MatchStrings` and

```
public static <E> ElementMatcherImpl<E> with(ElementMatcher<E> matcher)
```

in `MatchElements` type-erase to

```
with(ElementMatcher matcher)
```

which is no longer valid, starting with Java 7, as @Tom said.

If possible, rename `with(ElementMatcher<String> matcher)` to something more specific, like `withStringMatcher(ElementMatcher<String> matcher)`

Comment: Hello, yes this is an option, but with your suggestion I will break the interface. I'm wondering if I can solve this issue without break the interface in first place, otherwise I will do. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I have a solution, to fix this Type Erasure I have created an empty interface called StringMatcher that extends ElementMatcher<String>, so MatchStrings.with() has been changed to; MatchStrings.with(StringMatcher) and like magic the Type Erasure is gone. But I'm wondering if the original MatchStrings.with() above was already a subsignature of MatchElements.with(), in that case can that be a new bug in Java 7?